# How to show that the introduction and elimination rules for $\exists$ can be derived from the rules for $\forall$?

Tags: logic

*An instructive exercise, given the negation rules for classical logic, is to show that the rules for ∃ (for ∀) are derivable from the rules for ∀ (for ∃) and the definition of ∃x(A(x)) as ¬∀x¬(A(x)) (the definition of ∀x(A(x)) as ¬∃x¬(A(x)))*

What am I supposed to do here exactly? Assume that the rules for $\forall$ are true, and that $\exists x(A(x))\Leftrightarrow\neg\forall x\neg(A(x))$?

But what do I prove? How can I prove that some rule can be inferred from another rule without assuming that the to-be-proved rule is true?

Im not asking for a solution, i just want to understand what it's asking me to do.

Here are the rules:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*tl;dr* In the first section I explain what you need to do. In the second section I explain the importance of doing this. Since you didn't want to see the solution, in the third section I give the solution of a similar (but not identical) example problem.

---

**I.** The existential quantifier satisfies two rules. The first is existential introduction $\exists$-I, which allows you to start from the premise $A(t)$, and arrive at the conclusion $\exists x. A(x)$.

The exercise is asking you to show that you can still do the same thing if you have $\neg\forall\neg$ in place of $\exists$: i.e., you can start from the premise $A(t)$, and eventually arrive at the conclusion $\neg\forall x.\neg A(x)$, while using only the rules of the universal quantifier ($\forall$-I, $\forall$-E) and the negation connective ($\neg$-I and some classical rule, probably $\neg\neg$-E) at each step.

Similarly, to prove that the $\exists$-E rule is derivable from the rules of the universal quantifier and the rules of negation, you will need to show that starting from $\neg \forall x.\neg A(x)$ and a subproof deducing $C$ from $A(a)$, you can conclude $C$ using only the rules of the universal quantifier and the negation connective at each step.

---

**II.** Why does this matter? Because it allows you to eliminate the use of the existential quantifier from every proof/derivation: first you replace $\exists x. A(x)$ with $\neg\forall x.\neg A(x)$ throughout the derivation (which breaks the proof since the rules you apply are no longer valid), then replace each use of the $\exists$-I/E rule with a sequence of $\forall$-I/E and $\neg$-I/E rules (thus repairing the proof).

---

**III. a.** Since you don't want to see a solution, let me solve a similar example problem instead.

The introduction rule $\vee$-I1 states that from $P$ you can derive $P \vee Q$. I will show that given the classical rules for $\neg$, the $\vee$-I1 rule is derivable from the rules of $\wedge$, by defining $P \vee Q$ as $\neg (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$.

The $\vee$-I1 rule lets us start from $P$, and allows us to conclude $P \vee Q$. So we need to show that we can start from $P$, and using only the rules $\wedge$-I/E1/E2,  $\neg$-I and $\neg\neg$-E, we can conclude $\neg (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$.

So start from $P$. Assume $\neg P \wedge \neg Q$. From this assumption, we can get $\neg P$ by $\wedge$-E1. We now have both $P$ and $\neg P$, a contradiction. By $\neg$-I, we can now discharge the assumption $\neg P \wedge \neg Q$ and conclude $\neg (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$. This is what we had to show: starting from $P$, we concluded $\neg (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$, using only the rules of $\wedge$ and $\neg$.

**III. b.** The elimination rule $\vee$-E states that starting from $P \vee Q$, and two subproofs, one deducing $C$ from the assumption $P$, and another deducing $C$ from the assumption $Q$, we can deduce $C$.

I will now show that starting from $\neg (\neg P \wedge \neg Q$), and given two subproofs, one deducing $C$ from the assumption $P$, and another deducing $C$ from the assumption $Q$, we can deduce $C$ using only the classical rules for $\neg$ and $\wedge$.

Call the given subproof deducing $C$ from the assumption $P$ "subproof 1". Similarly, call the subproof deducing $C$ from the assumption $Q$ "subproof 2".

Start from $\neg (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$. Assume $\neg C$.

Assume $P$. Copy subproof 1 below this assumption to deduce $C$. This contradicts our assumption of $\neg C$, so we can use $\neg$-I to discharge the assumption $P$ and conclude $\neg P$.

Now assume $Q$. Copy subproof 2 below this assumption to deduce $C$. This contradicts our assumption of $\neg C$, so we can use $\neg$-I to discharge the assumption $Q$ and conclude $\neg Q$.

We have derived $\neg P$ and $\neg Q$ above. So we can use $\wedge$-I to deduce $\neg P \wedge \neg Q$. But this contradicts our starting point $\neg (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$. Therefore, we can use $\neg$-I to discharge the assumption $\neg C$ and get $\neg \neg C$. Finally, we can apply the classical rule $\neg\neg$-E to get $C$, as desired.

Comment: When proving  $\exists$-E, How do I use " subproof deducing $C$ from $A(a)$" as a given? Would it be $A(a)\vdash C$

Comment: @lightyourassonfire: I added another example (III.b.) which makes use of such a subproof assumption. Hopefully that will make things clear. (Note: the strategy used in III.b. constitues a fairly major spoiler for the original exercise)