# How do I show that some rule is derivable from another rule?

Tags: logic

I know that $P\rightarrow Q$ means $Q$ can be derived from $P$. For example $\forall x(x=2\rightarrow x\neq 3)$, and you would prove this by assuming $x=2$ and showing that $x$ is not $3$.

But I dont really understand what it means to prove $P\rightarrow Q$, when $P$ and $Q$ are some kind of rules.

For example: [How to show that the introduction and elimination rules for $\exists$ can be derived from the rules for $\forall$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4711849/how-to-show-that-the-introduction-and-elimination-rules-for-exists-can-be-der)

If you assume that some rule $P$ is true, how would you show that some other rule $Q$ is also true?

For example to show that the existential introduction rule can be derived from the universal elimination and introduction rules, you would assume the universal elimnation and introduction rules are true, but how do you exactly show that the existential introduciton rule is true aswell?

Comment: Constructing the appropriate derivation.

Comment: But P and Q are propositions and not rules.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think he is misusing $\to$ and wants to discuss derived rules.

Comment: And he's misusing "true": rules are not true or false, they are, well, just rules.

Comment: The answer is in the answer to the linked post.

Comment: The approach in general is: start from the premise(s) of the new rule and derive its conclusion using the already available rules.

Comment: Assume $A(t)$ and assume $\forall x \lnot A(x)$. From this, by $(\forall \text E)$ derive $\lnot A(t)$. Now you have a contradiction and conclude with $\lnot \forall x \lnot A(x)$ using $(\lnot \text I)$. This is the way to derive $(\exists \text I)$ rule.

Answer (score 0):

To show that a rule is derivable, you simply need to show a derivation from the premises of the rule to the conclusion of the rule using the existing rules. E.g. to show that the rule $\exists I$ is derivable from the rules for $\forall$, provide a proof of $\neg \forall x \neg A(x)$  (which by definition is equlvalent to $\exists x A(x)$) from $A(t)$ using (some of) the rules $\forall I$, $\forall E$, $\neg I$, $\neg E$. A rule being derivable then means that you can abbreviate this already possible but lenghtier proof into a new rule with just the premise and the conclusion.