# Prove $\exists$-$E$ can be derived from $\forall$-$E$ and $\forall-I$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

Here are the definitions of the rules:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This answer helped me to prove the $\exists$-$I$ rule, but im struggling to prove $\exists$-$E$
[How to show that the introduction and elimination rules for $\exists$ can be derived from the rules for $\forall$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4711849/how-to-show-that-the-introduction-and-elimination-rules-for-exists-can-be-der)

So basically, im supposed to show that given $\neg\forall x\neg A(x)$ and a subproof having $A(a)$ as a premise and proving $C$, that we may conclude $C$?

So i should probably start my assuming $\neg\forall x\neg A(x)$ and that there's a subproof that proves $A(a)\rightarrow C$? But I cant figure out what to do next.

Btw, is $A(a)\rightarrow C$ valid? Wouldnt that mean $\exists x(A(x)\rightarrow C)$, which then also means $\neg\forall x\neg (A(x)\rightarrow C)$ Maybe I could do something with that?